# How to make Clip-path work properly in firefox [mix of % and px values]

Tags: firefox, clip-path

It works in Chrome well

```
.mask {
-webkit-clip-path: polygon( 10px 0, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%, 10px 0%);
clip-path: polygon( 10px 0, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%, 10px 0%);}
```

How to combine px and % in Firefox
I made

```
 <svg width="0" height="0"><defs><clipPath id="mask" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
  <polygon points="0.1 0, 1 0, 1 1, 0 1,.1 0" /></polygon>
</clipPath></defs></svg>
```

It works with percents fine. But how to combine ?